# Python - Ibpy return valid order id

Tags: python, trading, interactive-brokers, ibpy

My code:

```
from ib.opt import Connection
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.ext.Order import Order
from time import sleep


def get_valid_order_id(msg):    
    global oid
    oid = msg.orderId


def error_handler(msg):    
    print ("Server Error:", msg)


def create_contract(symbol, sec_type, exch, prim_exch, curr):    
    contract = Contract()
    contract.m_symbol = symbol
    contract.m_secType = sec_type
    contract.m_exchange = exch
    contract.m_primaryExch = prim_exch
    contract.m_currency = curr
    return contract


def create_order(action, quantity):
    order = Order()
    order.m_orderType = 'MKT'
    order.m_totalQuantity = quantity
    order.m_action = action
    return order


oid = 0
cid = 100
port = 7498
conn = None

# connection
conn = Connection.create(port=port,clientId=cid)
conn.connect()

# register
conn.register(get_valid_order_id, 'NextValidId')
conn.register(error_handler, 'Error')

#order
contract = create_contract('TSLA','STK','SMART','SMART','USD')
order = create_order('buy', 1)

print(1)
conn.placeOrder(oid, contract, order)
```

1st Result: (order completed)

```
Server Version: 76
TWS Time at connection:20171101 02:07:03 CST
1Server Error:
 <error id=-1, errorCode=2104, errorMsg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture>
Server Error: <error id=-1, errorCode=2104, errorMsg=Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm>
Server Error: <error id=-1, errorCode=2104, errorMsg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.us>
Server Error: <error id=-1, errorCode=2104, errorMsg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm>
Server Error: <error id=-1, errorCode=2106, errorMsg=HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds>
```

If the last two code swapped:

```
conn.placeOrder(oid, contract, order)
print(1)
```

2nd Result: (order failed)

```
Server Version: 76
TWS Time at connection:20171101 02:11:20 CST
Server Error: 1<error id=-1, errorCode=2104, errorMsg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture>

Server Error: <error id=-1, errorCode=2104, errorMsg=Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm>
Server Error: <error id=-1, errorCode=2104, errorMsg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.us>
Server Error: <error id=-1, errorCode=2104, errorMsg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm>
Server Error: <error id=-1, errorCode=2106, errorMsg=HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds>
Server Error: <error id=0, errorCode=10149, errorMsg=Invalid order id: 0>
```

Why so funny and how to do it properly?
I just want to get a valid order id to order.
I am not a very good programmer, i don't know how a listener is work.
Please explain it as easy as possible. Thanks a lot!

Ibpy: https://github.com/blampe/IbPy

Comment: 99% probability that whatever differences you are getting are not due to having swapped those two lines but to something else. Anyway it looks like you need to create a valid order id in some other way (check the doc) before you call `placeOrder`, which expects to receive that id in its first parameter. Currently you are passing 0 as the order id.

Comment: Did you succeed to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: In the first **conn.placeOrder()** call you used the initial **oid=0** value. You can't use it again - the IB server assigned it to your order when it was accepted - so you got an error when you try to reuse it in the second attempt. It has nothing to do with the line swap.

By the way, it is a wonder that your first attempt was successful, because **oid=0** is not always a valid order id. If you want to get a valid order id, you have to call **conn.reqIds()** and catch the answer in **get_valid_order_id(msg)** callback. The callback is prepared, but I don't see the **reqIds** call. You can call **conn.placeOrder()** only after the answer arrived and **oid** has the proper value.

Just a remark: your **print(1)** call was executed normally in the middle of the error processing. Observe the character '1' in the 3rd line: Server Error: 1...

Answer (score 0):

According to your result, the failure of 2nd or later order placings would be solved by disconnecting and then reconnecting again, please add the below code into your existing.

```
# disconnect
conn.disconnect()
```

For every time you are connecting to IB to retrieve data, place orders, get your own portfolio summary e.t.c, you need to run `while loop` or other kinds of similar logic and keep reconnecting IB.